# Composerのインストール手順はどちらが正しい？

Tags: php, composer

ドットインストールのCakePHP入門「[#04 CakePHPをインストールしよう](http://dotinstall.com/lessons/basic_cakephp_v2/35904)」で、Composerをインストールする手順(0:18)があるのですが、Composerのページに動画内で実行しているコマンドが見当たりません。

Composerをインストールするには[Download](https://getcomposer.org/download/)の

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '669656bab3166a7aff8a7506b8cb2d1c292f042046c5a994c43155c0be6190fa0355160742ab2e1c88d40d5be660b410') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

を実行すればいいのですか？それとも動画内で実行している

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

を実行すればいいのですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

それぞれの処理内容は次のようになっています。

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '669656bab3166a7aff8a7506b8cb2d1c292f042046c5a994c43155c0be6190fa0355160742ab2e1c88d40d5be660b410') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

1. `https://getcomposer.org/installer` をダウンロード
2. ハッシュ値を計算し、ファイルが改ざんされていないことを確かめる
3. 問題なければ、ダウンロードしたファイルをPHPで実行
4. ダウンロードしたファイルを削除

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

1. `https://getcomposer.org/installer` をダウンロードして、PHPで実行する

---

というわけで、「`https://getcomposer.org/installer` をダウンロードして実行する」という点は共通しており、どちらを実行しても同じようにインストールが行えます。

ただ公式サイトの手順の方が、ファイルの改ざんチェックを行っているので、何らかの理由で壊れた・改ざんされたファイルを実行することを防ぐことができ、より安心と言えるでしょう。